# Show links to folders in FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: winforms, folderbrowserdialog

Is it possible to make FolderBrowserDialog display links to folders? For example, if I'm pointing it at my desktop which contains links to other folders, the FolderBrowserDialog will not show them.

Comment: Your title and question are contradicting.. and both dosen't make sense.. what are you trying to do.. some more detail please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean shortcuts to folders? The FolderBrowserDialog won't display those because shortcuts are files and not folders and the FolderBrowserDialog only shows folders.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look for another option.

Comment: @Yoav did you find a better option?